# Redirect to a file in previous location

Tags: javascript, redirect

So this is my folder structure (this all being inside the htdocs folder)

```
myproject
 -- scripts

       -- myscript.js

 -- responses

       --response1.html

 -- index.php

 -- some

 -- other

 -- files
```

And what I need is code in myscript.js which will redirect me to response1.html. 
Now, I cannot just use `window.location = "localhost/responses"` or something because eventually this won't be at localhost.
I've tried all those "location.host", "location.protocol" things, but neither of them redirects correctly, they all go to `localhost/responses/response1.html` , rather than `localhost/myproject/responses/response1.html`

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: as `index.php` is ***inside*** the `/myproject` folder, that looks like your root webfolder, which isn't accessible from a browser at all other than with `/`

Comment: Did you just answer my question or tell me that there isn't an answer?

Comment: That depends on your structure, it's hard to tell? If `/myproject` is your root "web folder", you can't access it, and what you're looking for is probably just `window.location = /responses/response1.html`

Comment: Okay:
localhost/myproject/index.php -- index file location,


localhost/myproject/scripts/myscript.js  -- .js file location,

localhost/myproject/responses/response1.html  -- the response file location,

I need to get from localhost/myproject/scripts/myscript.js  to localhost/myproject/responses/response1.html . 
When I do what you did, it takes me to "localhost/responses/response1.html, which obviously doesn't eixst